# code being fetch from core data is not being displayed correctly in tableview cell label

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, swift5

I am fetching from core data and printing it on label. The problem what is being printed on the label has a lot of run off stuff. As you can see in the photo below. In each collection view cell I want it to print 1 element of the array. So if the array has [vanessa,taylor,bastista]. Collection view cell should print vanessa.

```
        var people: [Jessica] = []
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = newCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomeCell
    cell.backgroundColor  = .white
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
    cell.textLabel.text = people[indexPath.row].playName
    return cell
}
```

MORE METHODS

```
      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    fetchData()
}

func fetchData() {

    do {
        items = try context.fetch(Jessica.fetchRequest())

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.newCollection.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't Fetch Data")
    }
}
```

[link to Core Data Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIAom.png)

[pic of collection view cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgbuA.png)

Comment: You are retrieving data each time cell reloads. Please remove it and prefetch data during `viewDidLoad` so that you only bind it with views in `cellForItemAt`.

Comment: I ADDED SOME MORE METHODS IN MY QUESTION AND NEW PICTURE LINK CAN YOU LOOK. SAME PROBLEM.

Comment: You are adding `String` of the object Jessica. Please cast it to your object class and retrieve the name property from that object to assign in the label. Not `String` of the result. Remove the fetching part from `cellForItemAt`

Answer (score 0):

```
var people: [People] = [] //Any suitable variable

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = newCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomeCell
    cell.backgroundColor  = .white
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
    cell.textLabel.text = people[indexPath.row].name //retrieve the name from your array
    return cell
}



func fetchData() {
    do {
        people = fetchPeople()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.newCollection.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't Fetch Data")
    }
}

func fetchPeople() -> [People] {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return [] }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "PeopleEntity")
    let items = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    var detail: [People] = []
    for data in items as! [NSManagedObject] {
        var p = People(name: (data.value(forKey: "name") as? String) ?? "N/A") //check for nil
        detail.append(p)
    }
    return detail
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. I am able to enter the code but when I try to load the view controller with the collection view I am getting this error Fatal error: Index out of range. I added my question above. Thank You So Much.

Comment: @MaxMadill where did you put the code to fetch from `coredata`; the one that was inside collectionView `cellForItem` delegate? That should be inside` fetchData()` and after getting the data assign the array of names to `people`. Please update the code so I can help :)

Comment: I am confused on how to fetch the variable. Can you show me how to fetch the data. Say for example I am trying to fetch attribute string bat from entity named salad. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxMadill: I have updated the code. I hope this will help you to fetch data.